# Possible to call another action method within same controller and return as partial view need advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need some advice and know how to solve this the best way. Let me explain what I have done and want to do.

I have some graphics element in a Partial View and when I click on one of the elements, a javascript function is activated and some data that was collected from data-attributes on the element is then passed via AJAX to the Action Method in the Controller to just add the data to the database.

Script 1:

```
// Function to add new Timeunit
function newTimeunit(week, hours, employee, order) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Employees/NewTimeunit",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { a: week, b: hours, c: employee, d: order },
        success: function () {
            console.log('AJAX successful');
            //location.reload();
            // Call other script to update Partial View ???
        }
    })
}
```

Action Method in Employees Controller:

```
    // Add new TimeUnit
    public ActionResult NewTimeunit(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        var timeunit = new Timeunit
        {
            WeekNumber = a,
            NumberHours = b,
            EmployeeID = c,
            OrderID = d
        };

        db.Timeunits.Add(timeunit);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //return new EmptyResult();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // ??????
    }
```

After the database is updated I need to update the Partial View and my question is what option are the best? There is no point returning something from this Controller!? Could I call another Action Method (see below) and return that as a partial view from this Action Method or should I after the success in the first script call another javascript function that loads all the data into the partial view and update the page? Or are there any other options that are better?

This action method reads all content in DB and return it as a partial view:

```
public ActionResult LoadPartialViewContent()
{
....code here read data from the database and create the
model...

return PartialView("PartialView2", model);

}
```

Script 2, loading from Controller to partial view (I run this script when I start application to load the content in the Partial View):

```
    function loadView() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Employees/LoadPartialViewContent",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "HTML",
        cache: false,
        data: {}
    })

    .done(function (updateView) {
        $("#PartialView").html(updateView);
    });
```

I hope my question is clear and entitled.

Comment: Your changing data so your ajax call should be a POST, not a GET. And there is no point calling `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` - ajax calls do not redirect. Since your view knows the data (you just sent it to the controller), why not just update the DOM by generating html elements in the success callback? (your method need only return a value indicating the data was successfully saved or otherwise)

Comment: if you build your initial DOM elements from a model as an instance of an object, not the model bound to the view used to post back, your items should reload after post back is successful and the page reloads.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your comment! What should I use instead of this: return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); ? And can you just explain this a little bit more: Since your view knows the data (you just sent it to the controller), why not just update the DOM by generating html elements in the success callback?, not sure what and how to make this and finally, how do I return something to make this possible: (your method need only return a value indicating the data was successfully saved or otherwise) ?

Comment: You need to show a sample of the the html you want to update in the view (I assume its a table row?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes it's a table row. My thought was to update the complete partial view with a script, like script 2 in my question, but is it possible to just update a small part?

Comment: Yes of course. But you need to edit you question to show the typical html for one row of your data and indicate what your updating.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That sounds interesting! Always nice to learn something new! I thought I could right click on the page and copy/paste the HTML code for the table, but all code in the element for the partial code is not visible! But you have seen the code before since you have created some of it :) How can I view the code?

Comment: Cant really add an answer based on the limited info in the question, but have a look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yy78S3) for an example of what can be done. The controller method just return a json value indicating success, and in the ajax, success call back, the data in the view is updated

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not sure what to add, since there are so much code. But your example was really interesting, but I need to learn more about this way of handling the return. I guess I have to change a lot if I should use this technic. What about my way of solving it? Is it really bad to just use a javascript function to load all of the content of the partial view as i Mention in my question?

Comment: No, you can return a partial view in the `NewTimeunit()` method and in the ajax success callback, just update the DOM with that partial view (it will be marginally slower because you sending back more data to the view but still an acceptable solution)

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, nice, but in the NewTimeunit(), I have nothing to return as a partial view!? It's in LoadPartialViewContent() method that I read all content of the DB and return as partial view. That's way I wondered if I could call an another action method from NewTimeunit and return the model to that method and then return it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110383/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-3d-kreativ).